# what the difference in __cyg_profile_function_enter between gcc and g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I know little about `__attribute__` and `__cyg_profile_function_enter`. Of course, they are both GNU C features.

I'm learning C++ to compile Nginx modules. I always try to convert the C code samples to C++.

Here is a simple sample of C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int depth_ = -1;
#ifdef __GNUC__
    void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    void _cyg_profile_func_enter(void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    #define sustainable(fn, caller) \
        do {\
            printf("%d, %s: fn = %p, caller = %p\n", depth_, __FUNCTION__, fn, caller); \
        } while(0)
    void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *fn, void *caller){
        printf("Enter:\n");
        depth_++;
        sustainable(fn, caller);
    }
    void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *fn, void *caller){
        printf("Exit:\n");
        depth_--;
        sustainable(fn, caller);
    }
#endif
void sustain(){    
    depth_ = 100;
}

int main(){
    depth_ = 10;
    sustain();
    //Suture suture;
    //suture.sultry();
    return 0;
}
```

sh$ gcc -finstrument-functions ...

It displays `Enter: 101, __cyg_profile_func_enter: fn = 0x400645, caller = 0x4006ba`  and `Exit: 100, __cyg_profile_func_exit: fn = 0x400645, caller = 0x4006ba` circularly

This is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int depth_ = -1;
#ifdef __GNUC__
extern "C" {

    void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    #define sustainable(fn, caller) \
        do{ \
            printf("%d, %s: fn = %p, caller = %p\n", depth_, __FUNCTION__, fn, caller); \
        } while(0)
    void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *fn, void *caller){
        printf("Enter:\n");
        depth_++;
        sustainable(fn, caller);
    }
    void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *fn, void *caller){
        printf("Exit:\n");
        depth_--;
        sustainable(fn, caller);
    }
}
#endif

void sustain(){
    depth_ = 100;
}

class Suture
{
public:
    void sultry(){

    }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    sustain();
    Suture suture;
    suture.sultry;
}
```

Then I compile with

```
sh$ g++ -std=c++11 -finstrument-functions ....
```

It displays `Enter: 2, __cyg_profile_func_enter: fn = 0x400925, caller = 0x40099b` and `Exit: 1, __cyg_profile_func_exit: fn = 0x400925, caller = 0x40099b` circularly.

It's weird. Why the `depth_ = 100` works with gcc but not with g++?

Answer (score 0):

What function do you expect `fn` to be the address of?  I'm not seeing function calls in `main()` that should take place after the assignment of `depth_`.

If you're seeing repeated calls at all, they must be due to library functions, which could well be performed before the `depth_ = 100;` assignment.

Comment: __cyg_profile_function_enter() will automatically run before any a user-defined function. It likes a constructor to all user-defined functions. When I call sustain(); it'll call __cyg_profile_function_enter() automatically.